# Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I changed my Kotlin version from 1.6.10 to 1.7.0.

from this

```
 implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.10'
```

upgrated to

```
 implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0'
```

But **Hilt** throws an error. My **Hilt** version is **2.42**. Is there a way to fix this without downgrading again? It works fine in **Kotlin 1.6.10** and **Hilt 2.42**. But I want to use it by upgrading my kotlin version.

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the issue on my project. Did you get any solution?

Comment: me too! none of the below solutions worked in my case

Comment: @MohitLakhanpal It was fixed when I did compileSdk and targetSdk 32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved when i added it like this

```
plugins {
            id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' version '2.4.1'
            id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
            id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize" version "1.6.0-M1"
            id 'com.android.library'
            id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0'
        }
    
      resolutionStrategy {
            eachPlugin {
                if (requested.id.id == 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin') {
                    useModule("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.42")
                }
                if (requested.id.id == 'com.google.gms.google-services') {
                    useModule("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10")
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 23):

Dagger/Hilt version 2.43.2 appears to have fixed this issue.

See https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.43.2

Comment: Be sure to change both project and module level build.gradle files.

Answer (score 12):

You can add `kapt "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.4.2"` and the problem will go away, however if you are using *Jetpack Compose* then you will have to downgrade your Kotlin version to `1.6.10` as Compose compiler is not compatible with Kotlin `1.7.0` as of yet.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.6.10' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.42' apply false
}
```

Comment: It works by adding ``kapt "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.4.2"``

Comment: You, sir, are a hero

Comment: why does it work though?

Answer (score 2):

You may change your kotlin gradle plugin to the same version:
`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0"`

Here's my components version and it works:

```
hilt/hilt gradle plugin:2.42
dagger2:2.35.1
kotlin/kotlin gradle plugin:1.6.21
```

Comment: what will be the plugins for kotlin version 1.6.10??@ruby6221

Answer (score 2):

In my case it turned out that the Hilt version in the implementation and the classpath were different, making them the same solved the issue. A good practice should be using a version variable.

They were like this:
In the build.gradle file of the app module

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.39.1"
```

In the build.gradle file of the project

```
classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

it is saying that u have different verisons of plugin and dependencies

In your project level build.gradle file or Settings.gradle file check for kotlin version you haven't updated it while u have updated your dependency, just change the kotlin version to 1.7.0

Answer (score 1):

In my case that build error was happening after adding any new module to the project.

For some reason Android Studio (2021.2.1) is changing the
`org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin` version in the main build.gradle file after the module is added, upgrading its version to the latest one. This brings up the mentioned issue. Just revert this change, if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Just i upgrade Hilt to latest version (v2.50).

Answer (score 1):

You must upgrade Hilt to latest version (actually v2.50)

Follow steps for install Dagger:

1. Add dagger.hilt in your build.gradle.kts (Project:NameProject):

   ```
    plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.22" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.50" apply false
   ```

   }
2. Add dagger.hilt in your build.gradle.kts (Module:App):

   ```
    plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    kotlin("kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
   ```

   }

   dependencies {

   ```
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.50")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.50")
   ```

   }

   ```
   kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
   ```

   }
3. Create Application in your MainActivity package:

   ```
   package com.example.kotlinfundamentals
   import android.app.Application
   import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp

   @HiltAndroidApp
   class MyApplication : Application() {
   ```

   }
4. Add Application name in Manifest file:

   ```
   <application
      android:name=".MyApplication">
   </application>
   ```
5. Create class for example User class:

   ```
   package com.example.kotlinfundamentals

   data class User(
    val id: Int,
    val lastname: String,
    val firstname: String,
    val email: String
   )
   ```
6. Create Hilt modules to provide instances of concrete types:

   ```
   package com.example.kotlinfundamentals
   import dagger.Module
   import dagger.Provides
   import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
   import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent

   @Module
   @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
   object UserModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideUser(): User {
        // Implémentez la logique pour créer et retourner un User
        // Vous pouvez utiliser des injections de dépendances ici
        return User(1, "John", "Doe", "johnDoe@gmail.com")
    }
   ```

   }
7. Inject dependency in your Activity:

   ```
   package com.example.kotlinfundamentals
   import android.os.Bundle
   import android.widget.TextView
   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
   import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
   import javax.inject.Inject

   @AndroidEntryPoint
   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


   @Inject
   lateinit var user: User

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    val userTxtview: TextView = findViewById(R.id.txtview);


    // Accéder aux attributs de User
    val userId = user.id
    val userFirstName = user.firstname
    val userLastName = user.lastname
    val email = user.email


    userTxtview.text = userFirstName
   ```

   }
   }

I hope, I helped someone

Best Regards