# Dagger Hilt Error : app:hiltJavaCompileDebug

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, dagger, dagger-hilt

**Task :app:hiltJavaCompileDebug** error: ComponentProcessingStep was unable to process 'dev.kevalkanpariya.featuretesteduco.EduCoApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC' because 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' could not be resolved.

Dependency trace:=> element (CLASS): androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelFactoryModules.ActivityModuleComponentProcessingStep was unable to process 'dev.kevalkanpariya.featuretesteduco.EduCoApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC' because 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' could not be resolved.

=> element (METHOD): provideFactory(android.app.Activity,android.app.Application,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelAssistedFactory<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>>>)
=> annotation: @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory
=> type (ERROR annotation type): dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory

If type 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' is a generated type, check above for compilation errors that may have prevented the type from being generated. Otherwise, ensure that type 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' is on your classpath.error: ComponentProcessingStep was unable to process 'dev.kevalkanpariya.featuretesteduco.EduCoApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC' because 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' could not be resolved.

Dependency trace:=> element (CLASS): androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelFactoryModules.ActivityModule=> element (METHOD): provideFactory(android.app.Activity,android.app.Application,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelAssistedFactory<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>>>)ComponentProcessingStep was unable to process 'dev.kevalkanpariya.featuretesteduco.EduCoApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC' because 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' could not be resolved.

=> annotation: @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory
=> type (ERROR annotation type): dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory

If type 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' is a generated type, check above for compilation errors that may have prevented the type from being generated. Otherwise, ensure that type 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' is on your classpath.ComponentProcessingStep was unable to process 'dev.kevalkanpariya.featuretesteduco.EduCoApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityC' because 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' could not be resolved.

error: ComponentProcessingStep was unable to process 'dev.kevalkanpariya.featuretesteduco.EduCoApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityC' because 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' could not be resolved.

Dependency trace:=> element (CLASS): androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelFactoryModules.ActivityModule=> element (METHOD): provideFactory(android.app.Activity,android.app.Application,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelAssistedFactory<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>>>)=> annotation: @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory=> type (ERROR annotation type): dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory

If type 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' is a generated type, check above for compilation errors that may have prevented the type from being generated. Otherwise, ensure that type 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' is on your classpath.error: ComponentProcessingStep was unable to process 'dev.kevalkanpariya.featuretesteduco.EduCoApplication_HiltComponents.FragmentC' because 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultFragmentViewModelFactory' could not be resolved.

Dagger Hilt Version: 2.42Kotlin Version: 1.7.0Gradle Version: 7.4.1

what is the cause for this error?

I've used Dagger hilt as a Dependency injection framework in my project with version 2.42. In hilt_aggregated_deps all Components were generated but still I get hiltJavaCompileDebug : failed in Build.

I have also added below dependency to fix metadata but still the error is same.

dependencies {//Not a processor, but forces Dagger to use newer metadata libkapt "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.4.2"}reffering from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73061190/dagger-hilt-error-while-compiling-project\]

Answer (score 2):

The reason being that is from your hilt life

try to remove this:

```
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
```

> Hmm, the androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel artifacts were deprecated in the Dagger 2.34 release in favor of native Hilt API. The missing DefaultActivityViewModelFactory class is no longer in the Hilt codebase.
>
> You should be able to fix this using the instructions in the 2.34
> release notes to upgrade to the new HiltViewModel API.
> [Find it here](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/3257)

Just by add these line :

```
def hilt = "2.45"
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt"
```

Comment: This cleared the error out for me, thank you very much.

Comment: I've been debugging this for about 3 hours. I've now learnt the importance of reading release notes too. Thanks