# Hilt java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I'm facing issue while adding hilt dependencies in my project

plugins

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'realm-android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}
```

dependencies

```
//Dependency injection with Hilt 
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1")
kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1")
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
```

build.gradle project level

```
buildscript {

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.11.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.0"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.42"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

i have tried below answers from stack-overflow but didn't find the solutions

[Hilt Unsupported metadata version in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67744002/hilt-unsupported-metadata-version-in-kotlin)

[Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72765456/8112541)

[Upgrading Android kotlin version to 1.5.0 throwing error message on build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67410992/7666442)

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

Comment: kotlin and hilt not working together, I tried hilt 2.41 with kotlin.android 1.6.21 and works

Comment: @AagitoEx what if I am not having hilt in my app? Still getting this error!

Comment: this solution worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/77045693/16177121

Answer (score 10):

Adding the below dependency fixed it for me.
I did not have Hilt in my code but had Dagger 2.41

```
kapt "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.5.0"
```

Comment: You are a champ